# BIOS codes on Gigabyte EP45-UD3P cycle on startup

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

I have a Gigabyte EP45-UD3P motherboard and when I boot it up, all that happens is that the codes on the BIOS display cycle and keep coming back to '13' and '16', but they keep cycling.

The computer does not boot up, and I see no picture on my monitor.

As far as I know, I don't hear the computer rebooting a lot. It just doesn't boot up.

What could be the cause of this?

**Edit 1**

In response to Argonaut's questions:

1. I am not sure about the specific revision of this motherboard. I am uploading a bunch of pics, that I am hoping can help us answer that question. If there is anything missing or you want me to take a pic from a different angle, just let me know.
2. Award BIOS version -- I can't get into the bios to see the version.
3. I have tried resetting the BIOS. I took out the battery and unplugged, that didn't work. I even tried replacing the BIOS battery altogether and that has not worked either.
4. I have not recently added new hardware. I had an issue with the computer before, where it wasn't booting (so the symptoms were similar) and I just reset the BIOS (i.e. plugged out and pulled the BIOS battery for 10 minutes and put everything back) and it began working again for a few more months. But now, that's not working this time.

Let me know what else I should try please and I can try it and update this post.

Thanks!

See pics below:

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]
[image: Image3]
[image: Image4]
[image: Image5]
[image: Image6]
[image: Image7]

**Edit 2**

I just reset the BIOS again, this time by plugging out the PSU power cord and removing the CMOS battery for about an hour. Then I put it back in and now I get a successful boot.

I was able to get into the BIOS and snap a pic of the version information as can be seen below:

[image: Image8]

So the question is, what could have caused this? Just a dead battery, that I needed to reset the BIOS fully for?

Given that this is the 2nd time I am having this issue, I would love to be able to do some more troubleshooting to see what else could be causing this issue.

Comment: Have you tried using the backup BIOS? Methods to use backup BIOS listed [here](https://www.gigabytenordic.com/gigabyte-tips-tricks-rma/).

Comment: What revision of this motherboard do you have? There are huge differences; it's been out for years. What award bios version are you running (looking up the post code meaning  requires that info).  What have you tried so far? For example, did you add any new hardware? Have you tried clearing the bios? Have you recently updated the bios? Please provide more info and I'm sure this will be resolvable.

Comment: @Argonauts I updated the question to answer your questions and I also added some images. Let me know what else you need to know so we can solve this. Thanks!

Comment: The post error 16 is related to testing the systems interrupt controller (8259 device). This enters the area of "it could be anything".  I would start by removing your RAM one by one and seeing if it will post- however you need to leave one stick, so try swapping out the last one. If that v doesn't work, strip the PC down to its basics - disconnect all drives, DVD, hdd, etc. Disconnect all usb devices. Leave only one stick of ram, the video card, the CPU and the power supply connected. If you aren't confident about putting it back together, just take alot of pictures first.

Comment: If it posts then, add things back one by one until it doesn't. If it still doesn't post, it could be a bad power supply ( under voltage), a bad CPU (pretty rare) or an issue with the motherboard itself.

Comment: @Argonauts I reset the BIOS again, and now it boots just fine. Check the updated question for more details. What can I further troubleshoot to see what could be the cause of both of these events over the last few months?

Comment: That sounds like the power supply. Older supplies occasionally work fine in 'steady state' but don't respond adequately to the turn on (larger than normal) inrush current. Powering the psu off for a little while seems to give it new legs (anecdote: my old home server has the same issue). Its related to the entire system charge ( mostly capacitors) being allowed to discharge to some degree, creating a 'clean' power up.  To be clear: This is speculation, but I've seen it quite a bit.

Comment: You have an [Intel Board DX58OG](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards/legacy-intel-desktop-boards/intel-desktop-board-dx58og.html), not Gigabyte!

Comment: @Argonauts from the [manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/desktop/dx58og/dx58og_productguide01_english.pdf): `13  Basic PCH init, discrete device init`, `16  SMBUS driver init`. what these mean is beyond me, but maybe helpful for your diagnosis

Comment: @guest Why do you say it is an Intel board and not a Gigabyte one?

Comment: See for yourself: [Gigabyte GA-EP45-UD3P](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128358) VS [Intel DX58OG](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813121472)

Comment: Oh wow. Interesting @guest. Thanks for that. You are right!